# How to sort without considering special characters in java?

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

I wanted to sort a list of names and I used compareTo method and I have names like this on my list

$urya,
andy,
prince,
@rikesh,

expected output:
andy,
prince,
$urya,
@rikesh,

instead, I get:
$urya
@rikesh
andy
prince

What happens now is the name that starts with special characters come's first and then other names are sorted

Is there a way to push the names that starts with special characters to last.

```
if (this.firstName == name.firstName) {
  return 0;
} else if (this.firstName == null) {
  return 1;
} else if (name.firstName == null) {
  return -1;
} else {
  return this.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(name.firstName);
}
```

Comment: if you would like to ignore the special characters, how would $urya preceeds @rikesh, it has to the other way around right? Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 steam API one liner

```
list.stream().filter(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")).sorted()
```

Comment: Maybe use `\p{Punct}` to explicitly filter out punctuation. [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: true, that can be added

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$` to be considered as `S`. In this case, in the compareTo method, you have to replace `$` with `S` (similarly for others) and compare.

If you don't want to consider the `$` itself(as the question says), you have to replace special characters with empty character.

Comment: The names that start with special characters should be pushed to last in the sorted list whereas now the name's that starts with special characters comes first and then the sorted list!

Comment: That's because special characters come before alphabets in the ASCII chart. 
You have to sort them separately then and append them.
I.e., Separately sort names starting with alphabets and names starting with special characters and append.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few modifications and as per your concern, i have ignored the special characters:

In the compareTo method, it has to look something like this:

```
if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) >0)
                return 1;
            else if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) < 0)
                return -1;
```

and the output in console is :

```
before sort :[10-$urya, 10-andy, 10-prince, 10-@rikesh]
after sort :[10-andy, 10-prince, 10-@rikesh, 10-$urya]
```

**Ignore 10, 10 is age in my Person Object.**

Take a look at my classes, you will understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;


public class ComaprableCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person p = new Person();
        p.age =10;
        p.name ="$urya";
        person.add(p);
        p = new Person();
        p.age =10;
        p.name="andy";
        person.add(p);
        p = new Person();
        p.age =10;
        p.name ="prince";
        person.add(p);
        p = new Person();
        p.age =10;
        p.name ="@rikesh";
        person.add(p);
        System.out.println("before sort :"+person);
        Collections.sort(person);
        System.out.println("after sort :"+person);

    }

}



public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {


    public  int age;
    public  String name;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if(this.age > o.age)
            return 1;
        else if(this.age<o.age)
            return -1;
        else
        {
            if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) >0)
                return 1;
            else if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.age+"-"+this.name;
    }

}
```

Below piece of code does the magic. It ignores the special characters just when they are comparing and returns the sorted list accordingly :

> ```
> if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) >0)
>               return 1;           else if(this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(o.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")) < 0)
>               return -1;
> ```